# SQL is not reading symbols in PHP

Tags: php, sql

Good day to all! While Im tring to insert  ', ), (, and other smybols, sql is not working. I cannot insert the sybols. I made my db utf8-general-ci but it does not help me. How can I fix it?

My Query is :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $depart=$_POST['depart']; 
    $boshqarma=$_POST['boshqarma'];
    $mavzu=$_POST['mavzu'];
    $qisqacha=$_POST['qisqacha'];
    $hodim=$_POST['hodim'];
    $tel=$_POST['tel'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp, "upload/".$name);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO video (id, name, depart, boshqarma, mavzu, hodim, tel, qisqacha ) 
    VALUES
     ('', '$name','$depart', '$boshqarma', '$mavzu', '$hodim', '$tel', '$qisqacha')";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){    
    }       
}
?>
```

Comment: Post the query which you have tried.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO video (id, name, depart, boshqarma, mavzu, hodim, tel, qisqacha ) 
    VALUES
     ('', '$name','$depart', '$boshqarma', '$mavzu', '$hodim', '$tel', '$qisqacha')";

Comment: this is my query

Comment: Define `not working`. What is the error you get?

Comment: Please use prepared statements and bind variables, this should solve this and a lot of other problems.

Comment: just the data cannot be inserted when I try to write < bo'lim > ]things like that. no error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Why don't you check for errors through `mysqli_error`?

Comment: Here is a nice explanation on how to use php variables in normal mySql https://stackoverflow.com/a/7537500/4244684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $depart= mysqli_real_escape_string ($con,$_POST['depart']); 
    $boshqarma= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['boshqarma']);
    $mavzu= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['mavzu']);
    $qisqacha= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['qisqacha']);
    $hodim= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['hodim']);
    $tel= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['tel']);
    move_uploaded_file($temp, "upload/".$name);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO video (id, name, depart, boshqarma, mavzu, hodim, tel, qisqacha ) 
    VALUES
     ('', '$name','$depart', '$boshqarma', '$mavzu', '$hodim', '$tel', '$qisqacha')";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){    
    }       
}
?>
```

One more thing you are inserting id hope you doing correctly
in most of the cases, id is auto increment so we don't have to insert in query.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] VALUES ('' [...]

Field *id* is often a primary key so '' would not fit with the column description (usually non-negative integer).

By the way you should be using PDO and prepared statements for a safer use of your database. Good luck!

Comment: If the field `id` is defined to be an auto-increment-field, that is perfectly fine

Comment: Good to know. Just hope he did !